# Приравнять строку и элемент вектора

Tags: c++, строки, vector

Пытаюсь реализовать Азбуку морзе на с++, не могу понять, как сделать замену в этом куске

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        message[i] = azbuka[M[i]];
    }
```

Пишет *" не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "std::string" в "char" "*
Не понимаю, что нужно сделать.
Вот весь код

```
void eMorze(string& message)
{
    string alphabet = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    vector<string> azbuka = { "•-","-•••","•--","--•","-••","•","•••-","--••","••",
    "•---","-•-","•-••","--","-•","---","•--•","•-•","•••","-","••-","••-•","••••",
    "-•-•","---•","----","--•-","•--•-•","-•--","-••-","•••-•••","••--","•-•-"};
    int* M = new int[message.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.size(); j++)
        {
            if (message[i] == alphabet[j])
            {
                M[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        message[i] = azbuka[M[i]];
    }
```

Comment: ошибку исправить легко, но то, что вы пытаетесь делать, очень не эффективно

Comment: и массив индексов абсолютно не нужный(вы будто специально все усложняете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` - контейнер символов `char`. А вы в строке `message[i] = azbuka[M[i]];` пытаетесь присвоить `char` тип `std::string`.

Варианты:

1. Сделать `message` такого же типа, что и `azbuka`.
2. Расширять строку `message` с помощью, например, оператора `+=`.